# Inputting values into a nested dictionary using loop returning TypeError

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to take in the information of all the students in the school using nested dictionary.
But when I try to assign the user defined value into the inner dictionary's key, it returns type error.

All the information is in a dictionary where the inner dictionary is for each "class" of the school. Here is the minimum reproducible example

```
#n is the number of classes in the school
n=2
school_info = {}

for j in range(1, n + 1):

    school_info[j] = input("name of the class:-")

    for i in range(0, 2):

        if i == 0:
            k = "student_name :-"
        elif i == 1:
            k = "roll_number"

        school_info [j][i] = input(k)


TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

But there is no string that is being assigned another value. `school_info[j][i]` is the inner dictionary's key for which the value is user defined.

Comment: There's no nested dictionary. `school_info[j]` is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: Each class only has one student?

Comment: @Barmar no, that is also something that I wanted to be user defined, but in my provided example there's only one student per class

Comment: The value of `school_info['classname']` should be a list of students. Each student could then be a dictionary like {'roll_number': 123, 'name': 'John Smith'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of evaluating this

```
school_info[j] = input("name of the class:-")
```

Will not allow you to later do this:

```
school_info [j][i] = input(k)
```

Because `school_info[j]` will be a `str` (the return value of calling `input`) and not a `dict`.

It seems like you want to use nested dictionaries here, so maybe what you want instead is something like this:

```
for j in range(1, n + 1):

    answer = input("name of the class:-")
    school_info[answer] = {}

    for i in range(0, 2):

        if i == 0:
            k = "student_name :-"
        elif i == 1:
            k = "roll_number"

        school_info[answer][i] = input(k)
```

This is, admittedly, a guess, based on what you have and you may find other ways to achieve what you want after you have something that works.

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstood, but how do I call specific values from the dictionary? For example, I want the names of students of "Class 2", if the school has 2 classes (class 1 and class 2)

Comment: I'm unclear what you are trying to achieve. Are you just trying to list all of list of the students in particular classes? If so, then you may wish to start with a list of class-names, and a list of student names, and then for each class load the class-name into a dict along with the list of student names. It's more typical to do this with file-data instead of inputs (which can be onerous to input: it will require a lot of manual entry). In addition, you should probably review python's dictionary access methods: `keys`, `values`, and `items`.